# JQuery: toggle conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a toggle button to my website wherein it enables or disables the functionality of a certain feature, however while testing it, I bump into a problem wherein it does not alert even if the toggle works or the image changed. How can I make it work, any help and suggestion is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<img id="toggle-video" src="/images/Icons/10_device_access_video.png" 
style="background-color:#C0C0C0; height: 20px; width:20px;" alt="" /> 

<img id="toggle-volume" src="/images/Icons/10_device_access_volume_on.png" 
style="background-color:#C0C0C0; height: 20px; width:20px; margin-left:-5px;" alt="" />
```

JQUERY:

```
        $("#toggle-video").on({'click':function() { 
        var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == '/images/Icons/10_device_access_video.png') src = '/images/Icons/10_device_stop_video.png';
//        {
//          alert(video success);
//        }
        if (origsrc == '/images/Icons/10_device_stop_video.png') src = '/images/Icons/10_device_access_video.png';
//        {
//          alert(volume success);
//        }
        $(this).attr('src', src);
        }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is not working ?

Comment: @blunderboy the alerts sir that's why I commented them to show what I've tried

Comment: Works fine as-is http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Yt45e/

Comment: yes sir the point is the alerts should work, if you uncomment them

Comment: They do, provided you fix your parenthesis.

Comment: What is the `:` doing between the 'click' argument and the function? I think that should be a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the code which change the `src` value inside `{ }` of your `if` condition:

```
$("#toggle-video").on({
    'click': function () {
        var origsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == '/images/Icons/10_device_access_video.png') {
            src = '/images/Icons/10_device_stop_video.png';
            alert('video success');
        }
        if (origsrc == '/images/Icons/10_device_stop_video.png') {
            src = '/images/Icons/10_device_access_video.png';
            alert('volume success');
        }
        $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ArWw9/)**

Comment: But it's not working if he uncomment the `alert` part. Please read the question carefully

Comment: It works fine as-is, even with the commented out alerts.

Comment: @j08691 No, the `alert` will not work since he change the `src` value before `{` of `if` condition which results in invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine.

You are trying to alert variables instead of string

```
alert(video success);
alert(volume success);

alert(`video success`);
alert(`volume success`);
```

Comment: @Jack, well I dont think he was trying to alert commented code. It was just commented when copying.